# How to connect to ftp, having write privilegies

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, ftp, finder, privileges

I connecting to my ftp server with Finder, entering login and password.

After establishing connection, i'm in read-only mode.

When i connecting with some ftp clients, like Cyberduck, i can write.

How it can be done, using Finder features only ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa;jsessionid=D960A87FE65480958A396890FEC9F65C.node0?messageID=11286315&#11286315) and [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10900691) on apple.com the Finders FTP functionality is limited to read-only.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind additional software to be able to use FTP in Finder, there are solutions for that too:

1. [Transmit's "Transmit Disk" feature](http://panic.com/transmit/)
2. [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac)

Another possibility would be a free FTP implementation for [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/).